# Problem in Building iOS app for release on flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

I am facing problem in creating iOS version for release. I can run the app on iOS simulator with no issue but I can't create iOS release version with **flutter build ios --release** command.
I tried changing the xcode build system from **new build system** to **legacy build system** but no solution found.

**Here is the Output & Flutter Doctor result**

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/rakibbhuiyan/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.15.5+3/darwin/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:171:40: warning: incompatible pointer to
    integer conversion assigning to 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') from 'id _Nullable' [-Wint-conversion]
        actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = call.arguments[@"handleCodeInApp"];
                                           ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/rakibbhuiyan/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.15.5+3/darwin/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:174:47: warning: incompatible pointer to
    integer conversion sending 'id _Nullable' to parameter of type 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') [-Wint-conversion]
                            installIfNotAvailable:call.arguments[@"androidInstallIfNotAvailable"]
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In module 'FirebaseAuth' imported from /Users/rakibbhuiyan/Desktop/Final Projects/travel app/clients/lavtrip/travel_hour/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:26:
    /Users/rakibbhuiyan/Desktop/Final Projects/travel app/clients/lavtrip/travel_hour/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Firebase/Auth/Source/Public/FIRActionCodeSettings.h:84:39: note: passing
    argument to parameter 'installIfNotAvailable' here
              installIfNotAvailable:(BOOL)installIfNotAvailable
                                          ^
    /Users/rakibbhuiyan/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.15.5+3/darwin/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:77:1: warning: conflicting return type in
    implementation of 'application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:': 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') vs 'bool' [-Wmismatched-return-types]
    - (bool)application:(UIApplication *)application
    ^  ~~~~
    In module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/rakibbhuiyan/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.15.5+3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.h:5:
    /Users/rakibbhuiyan/Desktop/Final Projects/travel app/clients/lavtrip/travel_hour/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:91:1: note: previous definition is here
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application
    ^  ~~~~
    3 warnings generated.
    building file list ... done
    App.framework/
    App.framework/App
    App.framework/Info.plist
    App.framework/flutter_assets/
    App.framework/flutter_assets/AssetManifest.json
    App.framework/flutter_assets/FontManifest.json
    App.framework/flutter_assets/LICENSE
    App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/
    App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/flr/
    App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/flr/load.flr
    App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/flr/splash.flr
    App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/flr/success.flr
    App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/images/
    App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/images/empty.png
    App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/images/hotel.png
    App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/images/icon.png
    App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/images/restaurant.png
    App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/images/search.png
    App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/images/splash.png
    App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/images/travel1.png
    App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/images/travel2.png
    App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/images/travel4.png
    App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/images/travel5.png
    App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/images/travel6.png
    App.framework/flutter_assets/fonts/
    App.framework/flutter_assets/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf
    App.framework/flutter_assets/fonts/Muli-Bold.ttf
    App.framework/flutter_assets/fonts/Muli-Light.ttf
    App.framework/flutter_assets/fonts/Muli-Medium.ttf
    App.framework/flutter_assets/fonts/Muli-Regular.ttf
    App.framework/flutter_assets/fonts/Muli-SemiBold.ttf
    App.framework/flutter_assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf
    App.framework/flutter_assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf
    App.framework/flutter_assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf
    App.framework/flutter_assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
    App.framework/flutter_assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf
    App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/
    App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/cupertino_icons/
    App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/cupertino_icons/assets/
    App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/cupertino_icons/assets/CupertinoIcons.ttf
    App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/font_awesome_flutter/
    App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/font_awesome_flutter/lib/
    App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/font_awesome_flutter/lib/fonts/
    App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/font_awesome_flutter/lib/fonts/fa-brands-400.ttf
    App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/font_awesome_flutter/lib/fonts/fa-regular-400.ttf
    App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/font_awesome_flutter/lib/fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf
    App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/line_icons/
    App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/line_icons/lib/
    App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/line_icons/lib/assets/
    App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/line_icons/lib/assets/fonts/
    App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/line_icons/lib/assets/fonts/LineIcons.ttf

    sent 25254982 bytes  received 886 bytes  16837245.33 bytes/sec
    total size is 25249046  speedup is 1.00
    building file list ... done
    Flutter.framework/
    Flutter.framework/Flutter
    Flutter.framework/Info.plist
    Flutter.framework/icudtl.dat
    Flutter.framework/_CodeSignature/
    Flutter.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources

    sent 387933650 bytes  received 120 bytes  31034701.60 bytes/sec
    total size is 387885886  speedup is 1.00
    Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Development: Al Taqdir Badari (HK828HTZUV)"
    /Users/rakibbhuiyan/Desktop/Final Projects/travel app/clients/lavtrip/travel_hour/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App: errSecInternalComponent
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

**Flutter Doctor Result**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.15.17, on Mac OS X 10.15 19A602, locale en-BD)
    • Flutter version 1.15.17 at /Users/rakibbhuiyan/Desktop/flutter
    • Framework revision 2294d75bfa (2 weeks ago), 2020-03-07 00:28:38 +0900
    • Engine revision 5aff311948
    • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.12.0 9983424a3c)


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/rakibbhuiyan/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.43.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.8.1

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 80.0.3987.149
    • Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes, Delete your ios folder then run **flutter create .** and then configure the ios stuffs again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Delete your ios folder then run **flutter create .** and then configure the ios stuffs again. Thanks